# Spring Webflow : Skip view-state/ transition auto-select

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I wrote a spring webflow. This webflow have some action-state/decision-state then come to a view-state. 
Normally the user should select a button or link to choose a transition.

What i need is when the webflow come to the view-state, a transion should be automatically selected without user interaction. (In my case because of login response redirect from an external link).

Is that possible to do with spring webflow ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you would do instead is have another intermediate `action-state` or `decision-state`, that would either go to the `view-state` or skip past it to wherever the `transition` you want to take is going.